# Including PCL in a Android studio project with cmake

Tags: android, cmake, point-cloud-library, cgal, pcl

I am running Ubuntu 18. I want to convert an c++ script that I have written into an android app. I saw that Android apps can also run c++ scripts. My script depends on PCL (Point Cloud Library), CGAL and TBB. As a first step I wanted to make sure that I can make an c++ script depend on PCL in android studio. I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-studio-cmake#2) to create a android app that uses a simple c++ script. Next I would like to use the Point Cloud Library in that script. As a first step I modified the CMakeList.txt and that is where the problems started...

Currently my CMakeList.txt file looks like this:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Declares and names the project.

project("cmaketest")

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

set(PCL_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl")
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I have verified my PCL installation with this [example](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/writing_pcd.html#writing-pcd) and everything works fine.
This is the CMakeList.txt for the verification:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(pcd_write)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (pcd_write pcd_write.cpp)
target_link_libraries (pcd_write ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

But in Android Studio I get an error that eigen is not found:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> error when building with cmake using /home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/dan/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/src/main/cpp -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++17 -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/prefab/x86/prefab -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/dan/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=x86 -DANDROID_NDK=/home/dan/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/dan/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86 -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86 -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/dan/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=19 -B/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86 -GNinja}
  -- Could NOT find eigen (missing:  EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/dan/AndroidStudioProjects/CmakeTest/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I don't understand why pcl can be found in a regular project but not in a android studio project since I use the same lines in CMakeList.txt? Are there differences in how the CMakeList.txt files are processed in Android Studio? I also had to add a direct path to my pcl library for it to find pcl with Android Studio, which is not necessary in a regular project. (I did that with this line: `set(PCL_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl")`)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: What is your definition of PCL?  My definition is Page Control Language, such as PCL 6 for the HP Printers.

Comment: PCL = Point Cloud Library

Comment: Sorry, yeah I mean the Point Cloud Library.

Comment: I have since been able to get the Point Cloud Library running, utilizing this tutorial: https://github.com/bashbug/pcl-for-android
Still working on CGAL and TBB so help would be appreciated.